# How to overlay "transformed" element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML structure:

```
<div class="menu">
    menu
    <div class="submenu">submenu</div>
</div>
<div class="video">video</div>
```

The question is how to show the `.submenu` element on top of the `.video` element which has `transform` css rule without changing the structure?

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/YtAP6/1/

**Update**: `.menu` is also transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `z-index` to a positive number large enough:

```
.submenu {
  background: #c00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 40px;
  height: 100px;    
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: It's so obvious.. :) Seems like I have and issue in another place. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I found it - `.menu` is also transformed.

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk then apply the `z-index` to the `.menu` instead.